# Slash didn't find element working with variable(Python)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
/*[contains(text(),\'TextToFind\')]
```

When we find it through this xpath, Elements was not able to find it,
Once we remove slash its able to find.

It placed automatically, while passing through variables.

Any working solution with python-varible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python `format()` function to pass variable.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(variableTextToFind))
```